# Default setting today date for datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetimepicker

Im using bootstrap3 date time picker. 
Js code

```
$(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({

                sideBySide: true
            });
        });
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <%= label_tag :start_time, 'Start time' %>
      <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker4">
        <%= text_field_tag :start_time, nil, class: 'form-control', data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm A'} %>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All is good, but it is empty by default. Can instead of this defaultly put today date and time?

Answer (score 3):

use the below code:

```
 $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
                    sideBySide: true,
                    defaultDate: new Date()
                });
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  (line where default date)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker("setDate", '1d');
```

OR

```
$("#datetimepicker4").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date());
```

This will set default date as today's date

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  (line where default date)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: option 0 is not recognized! new error

Comment: still the same errors, i can do another way, just need to validate line with date and time. Problem in: if the line will be blank i got an error when create event. Can i do any validates here?

Comment: you want to validate start_time?

Comment: yes, i've tryed to validates: start_time presence true, but it doesn't work because of datetimepicker input line.

Comment: datetimepicker input line means?

Comment: was   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :start_time %>
  </div> - Validation worked
,But now
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker4">
        <%= f.text_field :start_time, class: 'form-control', data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm A'} %>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
     validation doest work

Comment: what values you are getting in params?

Comment: if start time empty or not?

Comment: `<%= f.text_field :start_time, class: 'form-control', data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm A'} %> ` Is this code working?